# Парсинг osm c#

Tags: c#, xml, парсер, openstreetmap

Доброго времени суток!
Есть файл, planet.osm([link text](http://openstreetmap.org)), размер в сжатом виде 30Гбайт, по существу- это xml.
Хочу реализовать на C# веб сервис, который предоставляет информацию из этого файла. 
И как следствие вопрос: каким образом добиться максимального быстродействия? Может стоит данные из файла положить в БД(только ms sql, никаких postgresql и пр.)? Может кто обрабатывал большие XML и может поделиться опытом. Спасибо за внимание!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Безусловно лучше один раз распарсить файл и положить данные в БД, чем каждый раз парсить целиком (в худшем случае) весь файл. Тем более файл не будет обновляться каждую минуту.

Answer (score 1):

Если не нет под рукой СУБД, можно попробовать разбить на несколько файлов (с подкаталогами или без) и получить иерархическую БД. Например:

```html
<xmlroot>
  <subtag id="1" path="C:\xmldb\subfile1.xml"/>
  ....  
</xmlroot>
```

А в subfile1.xml по адресу C:\xmldb\

```html
<subtag id="1">
  <Somedata>....</Somedata>
</subtag>
  
Главное тут, выдержать баланс между детализацией и производительностью.
```